# iOS: WindowsAzureMessaging.framework for ARM64

Tags: ios, azure, arm64

Where can I find the WindowsAzureMessaging.framework library for iOS 64-bit devices?

I downloaded version 1.1.3 from the Azure Website, but I can't run this library on 64-bit.
Someone has the same experience?

On the Azure Website they say that de Azure Mobile Services Framework is ARM64 compatible, but it seems the included Azure Messaging Framework is not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a new release is coming up this week:

> We will be releasing a version with arm64 support by the end of the week.
>   Sorry for the inconvenience.

https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/issues/232#issuecomment-38757956